# Is there a way to switch a texture between left and right pass for a stereoscopic rendering (3.1.2)?

Tags: rendering, scripting, shaders

Is there a way to switch a texture between left and right pass for a stereoscopic rendering (3.1.2)?

I'm creating a stereoscopic 360; one of the "subjects" of the scene is a person filmed on a greenscreen (filmed in stereoscopic 360).

I'm reprojecting the masked movie on a geometry: this reprojection, which at the moment is the one for the left eye, should be switched to the source for the right eye (when Blender is rendering the right eye, of course).

Comment: Hi there, welcome! It's not clear to me what you're asking. Can you just mirror the image? Perhaps include some images and try and rephrase. hope someone can help. :)

Comment: The answer to this likely depends how you're loading the video or image sequence. Please try to provide details on the precise setup of the scene: 1. How is the stereoscopic video loaded, 2. How are your projecting it, 3. How are you rendering the scene with regard to Blender stereoscopic render setting.  Please also add screenshots of your shader setup and scene.

Comment: Hi all, better avoiding the complexity of my actual scene.
Imagine to have a stereoscopic 360 movie (already splitted in two files, one for the left eye and one for the right eye)
You are using the movie (the texture taken from the left eye, for the moment) as a texture (on an emissive shader).
The purpose is to render this material in stereoscopy, using the "left eye" texture when Blender is rendering the left eye, and using the "right eye" texture when Blender is rendering the right eye.
Is it clearer?
Otherwise please ask, I will try to do my best to give you any information possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how to do this in preview, but you can do it in the compositor, using map UV and switch view nodes:

[image]

Comment: I already new about this method.. and unfortunately it's not usefull for my purpose.
Thank you anyways!